# Detecting a 404 error on a PDF <embed> element in Angular 14

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an Angular 14 app with an  element that I use to display a PDF. Sometimes, the PDF preview is not available and the server that serves PDFs returns a 404 error.

I can detect when the `<embed>` is done loading the PDF using the (load) output, see below. How can I similarly detect when the PDF fails to load? I tried using (error) but it the event binding never fires.

**Template:**

```
  <embed
    #embed
    [src]="src"
    (load)="loaded($event)"
    (error)="error($event)"
  />
```

**Component:**

```
load(event: UIEvent){
  console.log(event)
}

error(event: UIEvent){
  console.log(event)
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add a $ before `event` in the error function of your template ?

Comment: Your template looks correct but you're not logging anything in `load()` since the name of the parameter (`$event`) does not match the variable you're trying to log (`event`). Either change the signature to `load(event: UIEvent)` or the log to `console.log($event)`.